# Nginx: Add subpath cause infinite redirect loop

Tags: nginx

Hi I want to add a subpath to my current app url and redirect all request to it, example: 
https://example.com/ -> https://example.com/main

https://example.com/faq -> https://example.com/main/faq

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name example.com;

  rewrite ^/(?!main).*$ /main/$1;
}
```

I try to use regex to avoid the infinite loop on itself, but it still redirect, not sure what went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a capture for `$1` and you should make the rewrite issue a 3xx response if you want to see the result:

```
rewrite ^/(?!main)(.*)$ /main/$1 redirect;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.